# How can I safely look at the request body in a Django REST framework Authentication?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I've implemented a webhook. The caller provides a shared secret. They concatenate the request URL and body, sign it with the secret, and provide the signature in a header. To validate the signature, I need to repeat the process and compare the signature that I get to the one that the caller got.

I'm using Django REST framework. I'm checking the signature in a custom `Authentication`. The framework calls the `Authentication`'s `authenticate` method with the request as a parameter. I can get the request body from `request.stream.read()`. However, that consumes the stream, which prevents the framework from parsing it for me: when the framework calls the view the request has no `data` attribute as it normally would.

`request.stream` doesn't allow me to `seek(0)`. The request doesn't allow me to replace the stream with a rewound one such as a `StringIO`. My current workaround is to store the body in `request.auth` and parse it myself in the view, which works but is ugly.

Is there a way to access the request body safely in an `Authentication`?

Here's the version that works:

In `myapp/authentications.py`:

```
import hmac
from hashlib import sha1
from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed

class WebhookAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        actual_signature = request.META['X-Vendor-Signature']
        body, expected_signature = self.expected_signature(request)
        if actual_signature != expected_signature:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("Request X-Vendor-Signature did not match expected signature")
        return None, body  # Hack: preserve the body in request.auth

    def expected_signature(self, request):
        body = request.stream.read()
        raw = request.build_absolute_uri(request.META['PATH_INFO']) + body
        signature = hmac.new("the shared secret", raw, sha1).digest().encode("base64")
        return body, signature
```

In `myapp/views.py`:

```
import json
from rest_framework.views import APIView    
from serializers import SomeSerializer
from myapp.authentications import WebhookAuthentication

class SomeView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (WebhookAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = ()

    def post(self, request, _=None):
        data = json.loads(request.auth)  # Hack: get the body from where we stashed it
        serializer = SomeSerializer(data=data)  # I'd like to be able to use request.data here
        # Use the serializer ...
```

How can I do better than the hack?